# Hide and Secure files on server in Code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, filesystems, file-sharing, secure-coding

I am developing a web application for my client using Code Igniter and i need to hide and secure some ZIP, JPG and PDF files on server so that they are not accessible by non users. Only people who are logged in and are the owners of Files can access the files. This is very similar to secure file sharing websites. 
it is very similar to any paid file sharing site like only people who paid for files can download files. In my case only those who have uploaded and who shared the files with other can download files.
Please tell me how can i do this..
Thanks
Sajid

Answer (score 0):

One method is to keep the files above the web root (so not publicly accessible) and have the link to them point to a function that will check if logged in (or other parameters you want) and if everything is OK, then serve the file(s).

Comment: many firends suggested this solution to me.. but this is not possible. Because i can check the session on Page where users are logged in. Zip, JPG, PDF or png files are non executable files and i cannot check sessions/cookies on that files. an example is.
if a user has downloaded file on public PC then it will be stored in Browser history and a person who have some know how about Browser and computer can download that file just  by going  to history and then clicking upon that link.

Comment: @Sajid once a user downloads a file to the PC they are using, you lose all access control over the file.

Comment: yes i know this. But i want to generate dynamic URLS for files. Like you might have noticed at media share or 4shared etc. each time you download a file, each file has a different URL.